# How to make webpage article based?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my webpage article based. By this I mean, for example, on the main page you have article 1 and article 2, but I want to make it so that you have to click on the heading which will lead you the page containing the whole article, on the main page you should only be able to see a preview of the articles ( with "see more...) if you know what I mean ? How are webpages like that set up (html/css) ?

Comment: There are toolsets for such, even free ones.

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: Not my turf. I'm afraid overviews like [the rest](https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/wordpress-competitors-23-popular-alternatives-to-wordpress/) sum it up. And: [Wrong site/community for "external tool questions&recommendations"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't dynamically create a "article based" page only using HTML and CSS. You should rely on a programming language for web development such as PHP or ASP.NET.

Alternatively you can write on your own all pages you need. You should manually write all the previews and create pages dedicated to the article itself. This is not a good way.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I feared.. I don't know any php or asp.net [ :'( ]..

Comment: Oh well it's time to start some learning! It is a beautiful world. I suggest to start with PHP since in my opinion it's simplier. There are a lot of beginner guides out there in the internet, but first learn how HTML and CSS works and how they are linked to web-based programming languages.

Comment: Yes, I am looking at it right now. There's always time to learn something. Would you say that my html/css is bad ? (johnswork.eu)

Comment: Not at all buddy! Keep it up, nice works! I bet It will be easy for you to add some PHP to create what you need.

Comment: Thanks! appreciate it!